# crash when insert data to database via room:Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: android, android-room

Here is my StoreDao.class

```
@Dao
public interface StoreDao {
    @Insert 
    void insertList(List<StoreItem> storeItems);
}
```

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed:
This crash happened when try to insert the same data to room:

```
 io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: StoreItem.ts_code (Sqlite code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:126)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7598)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:986)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: StoreItem.ts_code (Sqlite code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:841)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:803)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) to @Insert

```
@Dao
public interface StoreDao {
    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertList(List<StoreItem> storeItems);
}
```